# Post request with Angular $resource to Asp.NET Web Api 2 not mapped by server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have found solution for $http service (which is passing data as JSON.stringify(...)).
But Im using $resource for my queries, and I have not found any solution for this case.

**WebApi Action**

[image]

**Angular component**

```
angular.module("owners").component("owners",{

templateUrl: '/angularjs-app/owners/owners.template.html',

controller: ['Owner',
  function PhoneListController(Owner) {

      this.AddNewOwnerAndRenew = function () {
              Owner.save( { name: self.OwnerToAddName }//here data passed like JSON
,function () {
                  //some code in success function
          });
      }
  }
]});
```

**Angular resource**

```
angular.
      module('owner.service').
      factory('Owner', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/home/owners');
        }
      ]);
```

**Template**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.OwnerToAddName" />

<input type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.AddNewOwnerAndRenew()" value="Add"/>
```

I have tried to pass `{ name: self.OwnerToAddName }` through `JSON.stringify()`, did not help. Any ideas how to make web api map object?